# Page arguments - hook_menu

Tags: 7, forms, routes

I have this two test menu items:

```
  $items['test/%id'] = array(
    'title' => 'Test',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('my_module_form', 1),
    'load arguments' => array('%map'),
    'access arguments' => array(1),
  );

  $items['test/new/%new_id'] = array(
    'title' => 'Test',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('my_module_form', 2),
    'load arguments' => array('%map'),
    'access arguments' => array(2),
  );
```

Here is the fr_module_form function:

```
function my_module_form($form, &$form_state, $id = NULL, $new_id = NULL) {
  dsm($id, 'id');
  dsm($new_id, 'new_id');
  return '';
}
```

Here is the problem. When I visit (for instance): test/my-test-var 
dsm(1) function returns $id => my-test-var
dsm(2) function returns $new_id =>

but when I visit: test/new/my-test-var
dsm(1) function returns the same as above which is:
$id => my-test-var so it's not $new_id as I've expected.
dsm(2) is still empty

Moreover if I visit /test/new/my-test-var/my-second-test-var I get:
dsm(1): $id => my-test-var
dsm(2): $new_id => my-second-test-var

Why do I 'tell' drupal in 'page arguments' which argument should be used? I always get the first argument from my_module_form.

How to separate it?

Answer (score 1):

Path parts are passed to the menu callback function with a zero index as the first path part i.e.

First url:
`array(0 => 'test', 1 => '%id')`

Second url: 
`array(0 => 'test', 1 => 'new', 2 => '%new_id')`

Your form function expects two arguments but you only ever give it one.

In your form function arguments, this: `$id = NULL, $new_id = NULL` corresponds to this `array('my_module_form', first_argument, second_argument)` in your menu callback args. So you are only ever giving your form function one argument from the menu.
Try this in your second menu item:

```
'page arguments' => array('my_module_form', 1, 2),
```

This will provide two arguments for the form callback function. Your first menu item will return null for `$new_id`, because you don't have further path parts to provide from the url.